# Cmake add external project?

Tags: cmake

I'm not entirely sure if externalproject_Add as most of the examples I can find on it is about downloading git etc/but maybe thats it...

Esentially I have :

```
FolderA // inherited project
> main.cpp
> CMakeList.txt
    > libFolder
        >someStuff.h
        >someStuff.cpp

FolderB // base project
> main.cpp
> CMakeList.txt
    > libFolder_Core
        >someStuff_Core.h
        >someStuff_Core.cpp
```

I want to "not" have to build static/dynamic/etc lib every time I make a change to project in folderB, I just want to include the CMakeList.txt from that folder in my folderA, FolerB cmake only has something like

```
set(headers xx.h)
set(source xx.cpp)
set(all ${headers} ${source})
```

Just looking for a way to say in projectA, cmake,

```
get_filename_component(libs"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.." ABSOLUTE)
SET(coreLib ${libs}/someCoreLib/)
add_executable(name, main.cpp ${coreLib})
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily with mordern CMake using exported target.

In project A:

```
add_library(projecta a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp)
add_library(projecta::projecta ALIAS projecta)

target_include_directories(projecta PUBLIC ...)

install(TARGETS projecta EXPORT projectaTargets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
    
install(
  EXPORT projectaTargets
  NAMESPACE projecta::
  FILE projectaConfig.cmake
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/projecta
)

export(
    EXPORT projectaTargets
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/projectaConfig.cmake"
)
```

This will make a target for `projecta` and export the targets for other project to use them.

If the project A itself has dependencies, consider exporting the targets to a target file, then generate a config file that also find the package of your dependencies. More on that on the [It's Time To Do CMake Right](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) blog post.

Simply add the path of your build directory in the CMake module path in the command line: `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/projecta/build`

Then, in project B:

```
find_package(projecta REQUIRED)

add_executable(projectb x.cpp y.cpp z.cpp)

# link project b to project a,
# adding include directories and link dependencies
target_link_libraries(projectb PUBLIC projecta::projecta)
```